# g++ doesn't warn when some class member is not initialized

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following code and I hope gcc can warn at either line 6 or line 17, but gcc doesn't do that.

```
zhifandeMacBook-Pro:CppCodeExample zhifan$ cat -n main.cpp
     1  #include <iostream>
     2
     3
     4  class X {
     5  public:
     6      X() {}
     7      int getA() const { return a;}
     8      bool getB() const {return b;}
     9  private:
    10      int a;
    11      bool b;
    12  };
    13
    14
    15  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    16  {
    17      X x;
    18      std::cout << "hello " << x.getA() << std::endl;
    19      return 0;
    20  }
zhifandeMacBook-Pro:CppCodeExample zhifan$ g++ main.cpp  -Wall -O2 -Wuninitialized 
zhifandeMacBook-Pro:CppCodeExample zhifan$
```

Can I get a warning for the class X's constructor doesn't initialize the members?

Comment: GCC trunk gives a [slightly cryptic warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/douEFm), but only with -O2 and -O3. -O1 gives a better warning and -O0 gives no warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC emits a warning using the  `-Weffc++` option ("Effective C++" option). I have tried this on all versions from 4.1.2 onwards.

```
<source>: In constructor 'X::X()':
<source>:6: warning: 'X::a' should be initialized in the member initialization list
<source>:6: warning: 'X::b' should be initialized in the member initialization list
Compiler returned: 0
```

You can see live demo on godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hcsPVF).

Comment: another of this solution is this option covers more warnings than I need.  is there any document about this options, I googled but found nothing.  currently I just want to warning this 1 situation.

Comment: Pls see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html for more info on `effc++` and other such options.